What proton.SSLDomain configuration should I use for an AMQP data producer/consumer?
I'm looking to connect an AMQP message producer to the southbound AMQP adapter, and an AMQP consumer/commander on the northbound AMQP interface of my hono instance.
Setting the proton.SSLDomain parameters just yields an proton._exceptions.Timeout: SSL failure. The qpid docs aren't really helpful in figuring out what I'm doing wrong.
How can I correctly configure this AMQP producer? For reference, my hono installation is based on the setup from the getting started guide, and the AMQP producer code is based on an MQTT producer that works fine.
AMQP producer code
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
from proton import Message
from proton.handlers import MessagingHandler
from proton.reactor import Container
from proton import SSLDomain

amqpNetworkIp = "localhost"
tenantId = 'zzz'
deviceId = 'yyy'
devicePassword = 'xxx'

class AmqpMessageSender(MessagingHandler):
    def __init__(self, server):
        super(AmqpMessageSender, self).__init__()
        self.server = server

    def on_start(self, event):
        print("In start")
        ssl_domain = SSLDomain(1)
        ssl_domain.set_peer_authentication(ssl_domain.ANONYMOUS_PEER)
        ssl_domain.set_trusted_ca_db("./truststore.pem")
        
        conn = event.container.connect(
            url=self.server,
            sasl_enabled=True,
            allowed_mechs="PLAIN",
            allow_insecure_mechs=True,
            user=f'{deviceId}@{tenantId}',
            password=devicePassword,
            ssl_domain=ssl_domain
        )
        print("connection established")
        event.container.create_sender(context=conn, target=None)
        print("sender created")

    def on_sendable(self, event):
        print("In Msg send")
        event.sender.send(Message(
            address=f'telemetry',
            content_type='application/json',
            body="{\"temp\": 5, \"transport\": \"amqp\"}"
        )) 
        event.sender.close()
        event.connection.close()
        print("Sender & connection closed")

    def on_connection_error(self, event):
        print("Connection Error")

    def on_link_error(self, event):
        print("Link Error")

    def on_transport_error(self, event):
        print("Transport Error")
        print(event)

Container(AmqpMessageSender(f'amqp://localhost:5671')).run()

MQTT Producer
The AMQP producer code is based on a simple MQTT producer, which does work properly. I'll just paste it here for reference.
import ssl
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# MQTT configuration
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 8883
USERNAME = "xxx@yyy"
PASSWORD = "zzz"
TOPIC = "aaa"

# Create an MQTT client
client = mqtt.Client()

# Set username and password for MQTT
client.username_pw_set(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

# Configure SSL/TLS
client.tls_set("./truststore.pem")  # For SSL without server authentication
client.tls_insecure_set(True)            # Bypass certificate verification

# Define callback for connection
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
    else:
        print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

client.on_connect = on_connect

# Connect to the MQTT broker
client.connect(BROKER_HOST, BROKER_PORT)

# Send messages periodically
client.loop_start()
try:
    while True:
        message = "Hello Hono via MQTT!"
        client.publish(TOPIC, payload=message)
        print(f"Sent message: {message}")
        time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    client.loop_stop()
    client.disconnect()


Have you tried using the amqps scheme in your server URI (instead of amqp)?
See https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-0.39.0/proton/python/docs/proton.reactor.html#proton.reactor.Container for reference ...
